# Power supplied by voltage source at non-inverting op-amp input

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-source

Take this differential amplifier:

[image]

Where Vout is proportional to (V2-V1). Both op-amps are ideal with linear output. How to determine the power supplied by input voltage sources? Power should be P = V*I, but in ideal op-amps input current should be zero, and so the power, but it makes no sense to me.

Comment: Can you post the exact question you were asked?

Comment: Here it is: "Calculate instant power supplied by voltage sources at input".

Comment: I'd say that would be zero, unless these "ideal" op amps harvest their power from the inputs somehow.  Is it possible they mean another voltage source providing power to the op amps?

Comment: As power supplied directly by op amps is a question asked later I don't think so

Comment: If the op amps are ideal, then YES the input power is indeed zero.  This is not impossible -- no work is being done.  The input voltages are only "sensed" -- only their potentials matter.  It is not necessary to flow even a single electron to sense a voltage.  So the input power's being zero is not a problem.  Is that what you're concerned about?  (In practice, op-amps will have small currents at the inputs, usually in nA range (pA for MOSFET inputs, maybe close to µA for ancient beasts like 741).

Comment: @Atomique thanks for your comment, exactly what i was looking for